# Are PostgreSQL and Rails linked? I can't verify that PostgreSQL is installed even though I executed the command "$ psql --version"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, homebrew

My ruby ​​version is 2.6.6, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my bundler version is 2.2.21, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I added the following command in Gemfile.

```
Group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I executed the following command.

```
$ bundle install --without production

Your /Users/****/.bundle/config config includes `BUNDLE_--LOCAK`, which contains the dash character (`-`).
This is deprecated, because configuration through `ENV` should be possible, but `ENV` keys cannot include dashes.
Please edit /Users/****/.bundle/config and replace any dashes in configuration keys with a triple underscore (`___`).
[DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which 
bundler will no longer do in future versions. 
Instead please use `bundle config set --local without 'production'`, and stop using this flag
```

I executed the following command.

```
$ heroku run rails db:migrate

Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ [My APP Name]... up, run.4644 (Free)
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.369011 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock
(7891184118159383580);
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.398530 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1
.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.415834 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (
0.9ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_intern
al_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.421025 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.422588 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
D, [2021-08-07T06:10:09.423522 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(****)
```

I executed the following command.

````
$ git push heroku main

<omitted>
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:
remote:        To declare a Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:

remote:        ```
remote:        ruby "2.6.6"
remote:        ```
remote:
remote:        For more information see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:
remote:
remote:        2.6.8
remote:
remote:        The latest version will include security and bug
fixes. We always recommend
remote:        running the latest version of your minor release.
remote:
remote:        Please upgrade your Ruby version.
remote:
remote:        For all available Ruby versions see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via
a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:

remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 44.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v30
remote:        https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com/ deployed to
Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/[My APP Name].git
   7c51f35..dba64f4  main -> main
````

I executed the following command.

```
$ git push heroku main

Everything up-to-date
```

But I can't verify that PostgreSQL is installed even though I executed the following command.

```
$ psql --version

bash: psql: command not found
```

Are PostgreSQL and Rails really linked?

Comment: Have you checked if PATH contains the directory where psql is installed. It might be that Postgres isn't installed. In that case, perhaps the migration ran on a remote machine running postgres. I'd have a look at `database.yml` file

Comment: "*psql: command not found*" only means the `psql` command is not found on the `PATH` but it's not proof that Postgres is not installed.

Comment: Isn't Heroku "Postgres only"? Why are you testing with MySQL if you plan to deploy to Postgres?

Comment: AFAIK `pg` is just the Ruby Postgres driver. As to checking on Postgres status see [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli)

Comment: Database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other. I _strongly_ advise you to use the same one in development as you plan to use in production. Either switch to Postgres locally, or use MySQL in production.